# Mock the country timezone you are running unit test from

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timezone

I have a client running on an "East US" Azure server. Some of the code that works okay in development (on UK server) does not on that server (East US server). I believe the issue is due to me converting a date string into a UTC date time but i would like to write a test for it to indeed prove i have solved the issue.

Is there a way to fake the fact my unit test is running in a different time zone?

For example, DateTime.Now should return the time in East US rather then UK.

Is this possible?

Comment: We had a similar problem. In short our solution was to introduce an Interface e.g. `IDateTimeProvider` and a wrapper for the `DateTime` class e.g. `DateTimeProvider` which implements `IDateTimeProvider`. Inject through Constructor Injection into all classes which need the `DateTime` class and use some `MockDateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider` for your tests.

Comment: You can use shims - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-shims-to-isolate-your-application-from-other-assemblies-for-unit-testing

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar - Ah, now that... is exactly... what i wanted!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can fake the timezone in which your unit tests are running.

Here's a simple class that changes the *local* timezone to the `timeZoneInfo` provided in the constructor and resets the original *local* timezone when disposed.

```
using System;
using ReflectionMagic;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class FakeLocalTimeZone : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TimeZoneInfo _actualLocalTimeZoneInfo;

        private static void SetLocalTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            typeof(TimeZoneInfo).AsDynamicType().s_cachedData._localTimeZone = timeZoneInfo;
        }

        public FakeLocalTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            _actualLocalTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
            SetLocalTimeZone(timeZoneInfo);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            SetLocalTimeZone(_actualLocalTimeZoneInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

The `FakeLocalTimeZone` class is using [ReflectionMagic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionMagic/) to access private fields (which are [protected by a lock](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cfd60300ced9acd1bfa417d89cfd9f0136ec07e2/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs#L69-L91)), so don't use this in production code, only in your unit tests!

Here is how you can use it:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestFakeLocalTimeZone()
        {
            using (new FakeLocalTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US/Eastern")))
            {
                // In this scope, the local time zone is US/Eastern
                // Here, DateTime.Now returns 2020-09-02T02:58:46
                Assert.Equal("US/Eastern", TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
                Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromHours(-5), TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset);
            }
            // In this scope (i.e. after the FakeLocalTimeZone is disposed) the local time zone is the one of the computer.
            // It is not safe to assume anything about which is the local time zone here.
            // Here, DateTime.Now returns 2020-09-02T08:58:46 (my computer is in the Europe/Zurich time zone)
        }
    }
}
```

This answers how to *fake the fact my unit test is running in a different time zone*.

Now, as user3292642 suggested in the comments, a better design would be to use an interface and not call `DateTime.Now` directly in your code so that you can provide a fake *now* in your unit tests.

And an even better choice would be to use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) instead of the `DateTime` type. Noda Time has all the abstractions and types to properly work with date and time. Even if you don't plan to use it, you should read its [user guide](https://nodatime.org/userguide/), you will learn a lot.

Comment: Nice solution and description!  For my .NET Framework 4.7.2, I needed switch from `_localTimeZone ` to `m_localTimeZone`, i.e.: `typeof(TimeZoneInfo).AsDynamicType().s_cachedData.m_localTimeZone = timeZoneInfo;`

Answer (score 8):

Simplified version using `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` in `Dispose()`:

```cs
public class LocalTimeZoneInfoMocker : IDisposable
{
    public LocalTimeZoneInfoMocker(TimeZoneInfo mockTimeZoneInfo)
    {
        var info = typeof(TimeZoneInfo).GetField("s_cachedData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var cachedData = info.GetValue(null);
        var field = cachedData.GetType().GetField("_localTimeZone",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
        field.SetValue(cachedData, mockTimeZoneInfo);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I had a challenge getting the other answers working with .NET 6 but this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

On our version `.netcoreapp 3.1` the answer from 0xced didn't work because the internal api looks like it changed slightly. I made some small adjustments to make it work there.

```cs
    public class FakeLocalTimeZone : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TimeZoneInfo _actualLocalTimeZoneInfo;

        private static void SetLocalTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            var info = typeof(TimeZoneInfo).GetField("s_cachedData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            object cachedData = info.GetValue(null);

            var field = cachedData.GetType().GetField("_localTimeZone", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
            field.SetValue(cachedData, timeZoneInfo);
        }

        public FakeLocalTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            _actualLocalTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
            SetLocalTimeZone(timeZoneInfo);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            SetLocalTimeZone(_actualLocalTimeZoneInfo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added `<PackageReference Include="ReflectionMagic" Version="4.1.0" />` in your unit test csproj file? Because the TimeZoneInfo private fields (`s_cachedData` and `_localTimeZone`) look absolutely identical in my version (using ReflectionMagic) and yours (using System.Reflection manually).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the small NuGet library (authored by me) based on both answers. It includes both .NET Framework and .NET Core (including .NET) solutions. It's available here:

- GitHub: https://github.com/dariusz-wozniak/FakeLocalTimeZone
- NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeLocalTimeZone

Usage:

```cs
using (new FakeLocalTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC+12")))
{
    var localDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Local);
    var utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDateTime);

    Assert.That(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, Is.EqualTo("UTC+12")); // ✅ Assertion passes
    Assert.That(localDateTime, Is.EqualTo(utcDateTime.AddHours(12))); // ✅ Assertion passes
}

// Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local is the one before setup
```